# Where are Steemit posts and comments stored?

Tags: p2p, cryptocurrency

```
r = requests.get(
'https://api.steemjs.com/getState?path=/myapp/@{}/{}'.format(author, permlink))
```

So, Steemit has this api for fetching posts.

Now I'm figuring out how to post and get comments here [Steemit API POST comments and GET comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013841/steemit-api-post-comments-and-get-comments)

But where exactly is this stuff stored. Is it stored on a centralised server or is it decntralised?

Meaning I can use the Steemit crypto client and get the data myself from the p2p network instead of having to rely on Steemit.com web API?